# Exclude the zero in the given data in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a list of integers.
Also, I have a function which returns True when the element is non-zero, and returns False when the element is zero (let's call it FUNCTION1).

So, how to define another function (using FUNCTION1), which will give us a new list and only include the non-empty elements?

For example, we have [1,2,3,0,6,0], and we want [1,2,3,6]

Comment: Programming questions should be asked on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is the `filter` function.

To filter out 0 from a list, you would say:

```
filter (\x -> not (x==0)) [1,2,3,0,6,0]
-- or better yet
filter (not . (==0)) [1,2,3,0,6,0]
-- or best of all
filter (/=0) [1,2,3,0,6,0]
```

If you want, you can substitute the anonymous function with your named function. It should work the same:

```
filter Function1 [1,2,3,0,6,0]
```

Comment: I'd like to introduce you to my good friend `(/=)` ;-)

Comment: @delnan Why thank you. Pleasure to meet you (/=). I'll add you right into the list. (I barely use Haskell, so bear with me ;p)